# interview-Java sorting program

Tags: java, sorting

Write a java program to read input from a file and sort the words and then the whole file again.
i have got the coding correctly for this, the input is read fully from the file, but still the splitting cannot be done exactly.

Please suggest me a proper solution to solve this problem in less time..

code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;

public class HariPriya {

    public static void main(String[] ags)throws Exception
    {
        long st=System.currentTimeMillis();
        int v=0;
        String line;
        List ls=new ArrayList();
        //To read data from file
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/hari3.txt"));
        System.out.println("The original text is:");
        while((line = in.readLine())!= null)
        {
          System.out.println(line);  

        }
        String read=line.toLowerCase();
        //Spliting the string based on spaces
        String[] sp=read.replaceAll("[-+.^:,!@#$%&*()~?]","").split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<sp.length;i++)
        {
            //Check for the array if it matches number
            if(sp[i].matches("(\\d+)"))
                //Adding the numbers
                v+=Integer.parseInt(sp[i]);
            else
            {
                //sorting the characters
                char[] c=sp[i].toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(c);
                String r=new String(c);
                //Adding the resulting word into list
                ls.add(r);
            }
        }
        //Sorting the resulting words in ascending order
        Collections.sort(ls);
        //Appending the number in the end of the list
        ls.add(v);
        //Displaying the string using Iteartor
        Iterator it=ls.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
            System.out.print(it.next()+" ");
        long time=System.currentTimeMillis()-st;
        System.out.println("\n Time Taken:"+time);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens? What's supposed to happen?

Comment: You should do your processing of the line whithin the while-loop!

Comment: Also don't forget to escape the special characters in your regular expression (and split by `"\\s+"`)